# HTML & CSS: Text in one line with span align right full visible

Tags: html, css

I have a question. This is my code

```
<div class="comments_item">
  <a href="/post/123">Post 123</a>
  <span> - </span>
  <a href="/author/321">Author</a>
</div>
<div class="comments_item">
  <a href="/post/456">Post 456</a>
  <span> - </span>
  <a href="/author/654">Author</a>
</div>
```

if the title of the article does not fit, it is circumcision line with an ellipsis at the end, means css. The name of the author should be fully displayed.
If the title of the article is short and placed in the unit, then the author's name should go immediately after him. DIV is adaptive!

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: ..and perhaps an attempt of your own?

Comment: Please be clear. what does  "it is circumcision line with an ellipsis at the end, means css" mean ?

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/hg9xt93d1/image.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the css white-space rule (and possibly add a class to the first anchor tag)

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to the first anchor: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Example html code:

```
<div class="comments_item">
  <a class="nowrap" href="/post/123">Post 123</a>
  <span> - </span>
  <a href="/author/321">Author</a>
</div>
<div class="comments_item">
  <a class="nowrap" href="/post/456">Post 456</a>
  <span> - </span>
  <a href="/author/654">Author</a>
</div>
```

Example css:

```
.nowrap{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```